# How to split a Pandas dataframe into multiple csvs according to when the value of a column changes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So, I have a dataframe with 3D point cloud data (X,Y,Z,Color):
[dataframe sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SykV.png)

Basically, I need to group the data according to the color column (which takes values of 0,0.5 and 1). However, I don't need an overall grouping (this is easy). I need it to create new dataframes every time the value changes. That is, I'd like a new dataframe for every set of rows that are followed by and preceded by 5 zeros (because single zeros are sometimes erroneously present in chunks of data that I'm interested in).
Basically, the zero values (black) are meaningless for me; I'm only interested in the 0.5 (red) and 1 values (green). What I want to accomplish is to segment the original point cloud into smaller clusters that I can then visualize. I hope this is clear. I can't seem to find answers to my question anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should understand the for loop well. Python is a great programming language for using the code of any library inside functions and loops. Let's say you have a dataset and you want to navigate and control column a. First, let's start the loop with the "for i in dataset:" code. When you move to the bottom line, you have now specified the criteria you want with the code if "i[a] > 0.5:" in each for loop. Now if the value is greater than 0.5, you can write the necessary codes to create a new dataset with all the data of the row you are in. In terms of personal training, I did not write ready-made code.

Comment: Thanks, I get that. However, the for loop will give me ALL of the rows with the given value. I want to know how to separate chunks of rows with 1's and 0.5's. Thanks for your response.